# What is the meaning of double bars and 2 at the bottom in ordinary least squares?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, linear-algebra, notation

I saw this notation for ordinary least squares [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html).

$$ \min_w \left\| Xw - y \right\|^2_2$$

I have never seen the double bars and the 2 at the bottom. What do these symbols mean? Do they have specific terminology for them?

Comment: The use of the double bars just indicates that we are using the L2 norm.

Comment: @MichaelChernick and the 2? Is that part of "L2 norm"?

Comment: Yes, like L2, there is also L1.

Comment: I think $X_w$ should be $Xw$ since $w$ is a vector

Comment: @ilanman Yes that is what was in the notation before the edit. I changed it back

Comment: @AseemBansal I am sorry for getting back to you late with this.  The lower 2 outside the bar denotes L2 as opposed to say L1. The upper 2 I think is there to indicate the quantity is squared which is sort of redundant.

Comment: [Similar question on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586245/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're talking about the $\ell_2$-norm (Euclidean norm) of the vector ($Xw - y$). If this foreign to you, briefly, the [$\ell_p$-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html) of a vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, is:

$$\|u\|_p = \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} |u_i|^p\big)^{\frac1p} $$

So in your case $\|u\|_2^2 = (\big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} |u_i|^2\big)^{\frac12})^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} u_i^2$ which is consistent with the sum of squared residuals for a linear regression. In the context of regression problems, you'll also see this a lot in mean squared error (MSE) calculations, and in [ridge regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization).

This is a common norm (among other reasons, it's mathematically convenient), so when it's obvious from the context, you'll see the lower $2$ omitted, and just $\|u\|^2$.

As mentioned in the comments, you may also see the $\ell_1$-norm:

$$\|u\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |u_i| $$

Which corresponds to the absolute value. Again, you'll see this in mean absolute error (MAE) or [lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) problems.

Other popular norms:

- $\ell_0$-norm: [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), or # of non-zeros in a vector, i.e. in calculating the sparsity of a vector. Technically this isn't a norm (it's a cardinality function), because you have a  $\frac{1}{0}$ term in the definition, but it has the form of a norm so we call it one.

  - This norm is the ideal norm used in inducing sparsity for regression problems since we really want to zero out coefficients, however computing $\ell_0$ regularization is NP-hard, so instead we approximate it with $\ell_1$ which is solvable via linear programming. It's also popular in [Compressed Sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing).
- $\ell_{\infty}$-norm: = $\underset{i} {\text{max}}$ $\{|x_i|\}$ for $i = 1, ..., n$
- $\|A\|_F$: Frobenius (Euclidean) norm, applied to a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} = \sqrt{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum \limits_{j=1}^{m}|a_{ij}|^2}$

Comment: The link to wolfram alpha was really helpful.

Comment: You write that the $\ell_0$ (pseudo)norm counts the number of zeroes in a vector—did you perhaps mean the number of *non*-zero entries? (This would be more consistent with what I've seen, and also would mean that $\lVert u \rVert_{0}$ would be the Hamming distance between $u$ and $0 \in \mathbb R^n$, as opposed to being $n$ minus that distance.)

Comment: Spelling error: "Frobenius".

Comment: Instead of "this is a common norm" I would've just said "L2 is the norm" ;)